# Maxwell distribution from velocities to speed form

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

From Boltzmann distribution: $P_{j}=\frac{e^{\frac{-mv^{2}}{2kT}}}{Z}$ with partition function in the form, $Z=\int e^{\frac{-mv^{2}}{2kT}} d\bar{v}^{3}$, where $ d\bar{v}^{3} =dv_{x}dv_{y}dv_{z}$ we get the Maxwell distribution for molecular velocities:

$P\left (v  \right )=\left ( \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{\frac{-mv^{2}}{2kT}}$

Now, I'am trying to understand how to pass from this distribution to the speed distribution. It looks that it is enought to multiply $P\left (v  \right )$ for a volume $d\omega $ of a spherical layer of a proper thickness in space velocities to obtain a speed distribution for the interval $v$ e $v+dv$.

Considering the above, I have some problem to understand the following,

1. Why exactly $P\left (v  \right )=\left ( \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \right )^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{\frac{-mv^{2}}{2kT}}$ is considered a velocity distribution, the kinetic energy in the exponent is not a vector, so there are no velocity but speed in this formula.
2. why a probability, $P\left (v  \right )$ multiplied by a volume give another probability. In my understanding the probability is given by $P=\frac{dN}{N}=fd\omega$ ($f$ is a distribution function) so  how $P\left ( v \right )d\omega $ can be another probability?
3. Go from velocity to speed distribution, how it is really done?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99331/226902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is the word *distribution*.

The distribution of velocities is a function $P( \vec v)$ giving the probability of finding a molecule in a velocity space volume according to the formula:
$$
{\mathrm {Probability~of~velocity~in~a~volume~d} }\vec v~{\mathrm {centered~around~}}\vec v= P( \vec v) {\mathrm d}\vec v. \tag{1}
$$
Notice that $P( \vec v)$ depends on the *vector* $\vec v$, but in some cases like that of Maxwell distribution, it may be rotationally invariant and the it is a function of the modulus of the vector. Still, what qualifies it as a *velocity* distribution, is the fact that the link to probabilities is given by equation (1).

The distribution of speeds is a function $p(v)$ giving the probability of finding a molecule in a small interval of speeds ${\mathrm d}v$, around $v$, according to the formula
$$
{\mathrm {Probability~of~speed~in~an~interval~d} } v~{\mathrm {centered~around~}}v= p( v) {\mathrm d}v. \tag{2}.
$$

The relation between $P$ and $p$ in the case of the Maxwell distribution  can be easily obtained by recalling that the latter corresponds to integration of the former over all the directions. Therefore, by using polar coordinates
$$
{\mathrm d}\vec v=v^2{\mathrm d}v \sin \theta{\mathrm d}\theta{\mathrm d}\phi
$$
and exploiting the dependency of $P$ on the modulus of the velocity, one can easily get the relation between $p(v)$ and $P({\vec v})$:
$$
p(v) = 4 \pi v^2 P(|\vec v|)
$$

Answer (score -1):

1. p(v) is the velocity distribution: understand the speed. Velocity and speed are only for high school. In real Life, nobody cares about the distinction.
2. P(v) is not a probability, but a distribution: i.e it is a density of probability.
   P(v) dv is a probability.
3. idem than 1